# Magento Bundle Selection Option Pricing Problem

Tags: php, magento

I have a single store running several different languages/currencies and pricing is being manually set to 'pretty' prices, rather than just letting the currency conversion do it's thing. The problem is, when I create a bundle product and add options under 'Bundle Items', if I set a specific, 'fixed' price for an item it is retained globally -- I am unable to change the price for the bundle item option on a per-store basis. Is this a bug in the bundle module or is there something I'm missing?

Comment: What version of magento are you running?

Comment: Ah good question -- Enterprise v 1.9.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to have not been support available for this in Magento EE v 1.9.0.0 but since upgrading to 1.9.1.1, if you are editing a product and switch to a specific store view, there is now a 'Use default value' checkbox for bundle item option pricing.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know this isn't a bug nor you are something missing. Magento just doesn't support different pricings for bundle options in different shops.

What if you use dynamic pricing and change the prices from the simple products accordingly?

Comment: Hey Tim -- looks like you were right, Magento didn't support that but I just upgraded from EE 1.9.0.0 to 1.9.1.1 and they seem to have added support for it, so all good now.